# WCF and ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json with inherited classes

Tags: json, wcf, serialization

I have run into another issue that apparently deals with inherited classes:

I have for instance this super class.

```
public class Person 
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And then a sub class:

```
public class Member : Person
{
    public int MembershipId  { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

When I return a Member with the following code, I get nothing useful:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
public Member GetMember()
{
    return new Member 
    { 
         Firstname = "Jane", 
         Lastname = "Doe", 
         Email = "jane.doe@doe.com",
         MembershipId = 10,
         Password = "*****",
         Foos = new List<Foo> { };  
    };
}
```

Classes / objects that are not inherited are serialized and returned in json format without any problems.

Is there anyway to get my Member object returned correctly, please? I have been messing with this issue and my conclusion was that it must have something to do with inherited classes and json.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I don't get any errors. It just hangs and says waiting for localhost in the browser. Nothing in the eventlog either.

Comment: {"d":[{"__type":"MyObject:#MywebApp.Entities"},{"__type":"MyObject:#MywebApp.Entities"},{"__type":"MyObject:#MywebApp.Entities"}

<- I actually just get this.

Comment: It is very odd. If I hard code all the values into my object, it returns a serialized JSON string without any problems. If I populate my object dynamically from a database, then nothing works.
I will update this thread as soon as I solve this...

Comment: Serializing it to xml revealed a lot of errors. Apparently IEnumerable and dictionary/hashtables are not liked during xml serialization. It must be the same problems during JSON serialization.

Comment: Nothing helped, although use of json.net did what the native .net json feature could not. http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

This line JSON searialized my objects without any hassle.

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyComplexObject);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended using JSON.net from Newtonsoft. I would recommend to use that instead of wasting time on the native json feature in .net.

http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: In addition to my answer here, I can see that I am double encoding JSON instead. Due to my ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json. I am now trying to figure out, how to return pure string/plaintext from my wcf service, so it does not get doubly json encoded.

Answer (score 0):

try this fix

```
[DataContract]
public class Person 
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Member : Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string MembershipId  { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually my theory about inherited classes and JSON serialization was flawed.
It works and I do not need the [Datacontrac] and [Datamember] decorators. Something else is wrong. Perhaps my structure is too deep and too lenghty.
I wonder whether JSON has some limits regarding size.

Comment: I never found out what the problem was, and nothing showed up in tamper data or fiddler. My conclusion is still that the native json feature in .net is not stable. I had to use Newtonsoft's json.net instead.